# How to handle server errors in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, backbone.js

In [Backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org/), how do I handle any server errors when using `fetch()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking, technically, how to respond to an error, then:

There's a couple ways to do this.

The most straightforward is that the various "transaction" function support passing success and error callbacks:

```
myModel.save({property: "value", property2: "value2"},{success: function(model,response){...}, error: function(model,response){...}});
```

or, in coffeescript:

```
myModel.save
  property: "value"
  property2: "value2
,
  success: (model, response) ->
    ...
  error: (model, response) ->
    ...
```

The other way is to, since Backbone uses jquery.ajax behind the scenes, use the [jquery.ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler.

If you're looking for strategy on how, from a "product" standpoint, to handle errors, I guess it depends on what you're doing.